# Struct has different size if the field order is different

Tags: memory, struct, go, padding, sizeof

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

type A struct {
    a bool
    b int64
    c int
}

type B struct {
    b int64
    a bool
    c int
}

type C struct {
}

func main() {
    // output 24
    fmt.Println(unsafe.Sizeof(A{}))

    // output 16
    fmt.Println(unsafe.Sizeof(B{}))

    // output 0
    fmt.Println(unsafe.Sizeof(C{}))
}
```

1. Struct `A` and `B` have the same fields, but if specified in different order they result in different size. why?
2. Size of struct `C` is zero. How much memory is allocated by the system for `a := C{}`?

Thanks.

Comment: 2. does some memory need allocated for meta data, like type info.

Comment: structs do not contain type info (and have no size overhead other than the fields), this is all handled by the compiler.  Interfaces, however, contain the type and the value.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### 1. Struct sizes

**TL;DR; (Summary):** Different implicit padding will be used if you reorder the fields, and the implicit padding counts towards the size of the `struct`.

*Note that the result depends on the target architecture; results you posted applies when `GOARCH=386`, but when `GOARCH=amd64`, sizes of both `A{}` and `B{}` will be 24 bytes.*

Address of fields of a struct must be aligned, and the address of fields of type `int64` must be a multiple of 8 bytes. [Spec: Package `unsafe`:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Package_unsafe)

> Computer architectures may require memory addresses to be *aligned*; that is, for addresses of a variable to be a multiple of a factor, the variable's type's *alignment*. The function `Alignof` takes an expression denoting a variable of any type and returns the alignment of the (type of the) variable in bytes.

Align of `int64` is 8 bytes:

```
fmt.Println(unsafe.Alignof((int64(0)))) // Prints 8
```

So in case of `A` since first field is `bool`, there is a 7-byte implicit padding after `A.a` so that `A.b` which is of type `int64` can start on an address that is a multiple of 8. This (that 7-byte padding is needed exactly) is guaranteed as the `struct` itself is aligned to an address which is a multiple of 8, because that is the largest size of all of its fields. See: [Spec: Size alignment guarantees:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Size_and_alignment_guarantees)

> For a variable `x` of struct type: `unsafe.Alignof(x)` is the largest of all the values `unsafe.Alignof(x.f)` for each field `f` of `x`, but at least `1`.

In case of `B` (and if `GOARCH=386` which is your case) there will only be a 3-byte implicit padding after the `B.a` field of type `bool` because this field is followed by a field of type `int` (which has size of 4 bytes) and not `int64`.

Align of `int` is 4 bytes if `GOARCH=386`, and 8 bytes if `GOARCH=amd64`:

```
fmt.Println(unsafe.Alignof((int(0))))   // Prints 4 if GOARCH=386, and 8 if GOARCH=amd64
```

Use [`unsafe.Offsetof()`](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/#Offsetof) to find out the offsets of fields:

```
// output 24
a := A{}
fmt.Println(unsafe.Sizeof(a),
    unsafe.Offsetof(a.a), unsafe.Offsetof(a.b), unsafe.Offsetof(a.c))

// output 16
b := B{}
fmt.Println(unsafe.Sizeof(b),
    unsafe.Offsetof(b.b), unsafe.Offsetof(b.a), unsafe.Offsetof(b.c))

// output 0
fmt.Println(unsafe.Sizeof(C{}))

var i int
fmt.Println(unsafe.Sizeof(i))
```

Output if `GOARCH=386` (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/JovERjbY0V)):

```
24 0 8 16
16 0 8 12
0
4
```

Output if `GOARCH=amd64`:

```
24 0 8 16
24 0 8 16
0
8
```

### 2. Zero size values

[Spec: Size alignment guarantees:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Size_and_alignment_guarantees)

> A struct or array type has size zero if it contains no fields (or elements, respectively) that have a size greater than zero. **Two distinct zero-size variables may have the same address in memory.**

So the spec just gives a hint to use the same memory address but it's not a requirement. But current implementations follow it. That is, no memory will be allocated for values of types having a size of zero, this includes the empty struct `struct{}` and arrays of zero length, e.g. `[0]int`, or arrays whose elements has a size of zero (and with arbitrary length).

See this example:

```
a := struct{}{}
b := struct{}{}
c := [0]int{}
d := [3]struct{}{}

fmt.Printf("%p %p %p %p %p", &a, &b, &c, &d, &d[2])
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/lv87mVaKuL)): All the addresses are the same.

```
0x21cd7c 0x21cd7c 0x21cd7c 0x21cd7c 0x21cd7c
```

---

For an interesting and related topic, read: [**Dave Cheney: Padding is hard**](http://dave.cheney.net/2015/10/09/padding-is-hard)