# Why position of `[0]byte` in the struct matters?

Tags: memory, go, struct, padding, sizeof

`[0]byte` in golang should not take any memory space. But these two structs have different sizes.

```
type bar2 struct {
    A int
    _ [0]byte
}

type bar3 struct {
    _ [0]byte
    A int   
}
```

So why the position of `[0]byte` matters here?

By the way, I use `unsafe.Sizeof()` method to check the struct size. See the [full example](https://play.golang.org/p/oAnH2XodPa) .

Comment: What are the sizes?

Comment: size of bar2:8, size of bar3:4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is due to a *tricky* padding.

First please allow me to slightly rename the structs and fields so it'll be easier to talk about them:

```
type bar1 struct {
    A [0]byte
    I int
}

type bar2 struct {
    I int
    A [0]byte
}
```

This of course doesn't change the size and offsets as can be verified on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/NcTeFpDrJi):

```
bar1 size:     4
bar1.A offset: 0
bar1.I offset: 0

bar2 size:     8
bar2.I offset: 0
bar2.A offset: 4
```

The size of a value of type `[0]byte` is zero, so it is perfectly valid in  `bar1` to not reserve any space for the first field (`bar1.A`), and lay out the `bar1.I` field with 0 offset.

The question is: why can't the compiler do the same in the 2nd case (with `bar2`)?

A field must have an address that must be after the memory area reserved for the previous field. In the first case the first field `bar1.A` has 0 size, so the 2nd field may have 0 offset, it will not "overlap" with the first field.

In case of `bar2`, the second field cannot have an address (and therefore an offset) that overlaps with the first field, so its offset cannot be less than the size of `int` which is 4 bytes in case of 32-bit architectures (and 8 bytes in case of 64-bit arch).

This still seems ok. But since `bar2.A` has zero size, why can't the size of the struct `bar2` be just that: 4 bytes (or 8 in 64-bit arch)?

This is because it is perfectly **valid to take the address of fields (and variables) that have 0 size**. Ok, so what?

In case of `bar2`, the compiler has to insert a 4 (or 8) byte padding, else taking the address of a `bar2.A` field would point **outside of the memory area** reserved for a value of type `bar2`.

As an example, **without padding** a value of `bar2` may have an address of `0x100`, size 4, so memory reserved for the struct value has address range `0x100 .. 0x103`. Address of `bar2.A` would be `0x104`, that is outside of the struct's memory. In case of an array of this struct (e.g. `x [5]bar2`), if the array starts at `0x100`, address of `x[0]` would be `0x100`, address of `x[0].A` would be `0x104`, and address of the subsequent element `x[1]` would also be `0x104` but that's the address of another struct value! Not cool.

To avoid this, the compiler inserts a padding (which will be 4 or 8 bytes depending on the arch), so that taking the address of `bar2.A` will not result in an address being outside of the struct's memory, which otherwise could raise questions and cause problems regarding garbage collection (e.g. if only address of `bar2.A` is kept but not the struct or another pointer to it or its other fields, the whole struct should not be garbage collected, but since no pointer points to its memory area, it would seem to be valid to do so). The inserted padding will be 4 (or 8) bytes, because [Spec: Size and alignment guarantees:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Size_and_alignment_guarantees)

> For a variable `x` of struct type: `unsafe.Alignof(x)` is the largest of all the values `unsafe.Alignof(x.f)` for each field `f` of `x`, but at least `1`.

If this is so, adding an additional `int` field would make the size of both structs equal:

```
type bar1 struct {
    I int
    A [0]byte
    X int
}

type bar2 struct {
    A [0]byte
    I int
    X int
}
```

And truly they both have 8 bytes on 32-bit arch (and 16 bytes on 64-bit arch) (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/SBweaAzE2b)):

```
bar1 size:     8
bar1.I offset: 0
bar1.A offset: 4
bar1.X offset: 4

bar2 size:     8
bar2.A offset: 0
bar2.I offset: 0
bar2.X offset: 4
```

See related question: [Struct has different size if the field order is different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34219232/struct-has-different-size-if-the-field-order-is-different/34219916#34219916)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is "holes":

> Holes are the unused spaces added by the compiler to ensure that the
>   following field or element is properly aligned relative to the start
>   of the struct or array [1]

For example (numbers based on whatever hardware the go playground is using):

```
struct {bool; float64; int16} // 24 bytes
struct {float64; bool; int16} // 16 bytes
```

You can verify the layout of a struct using:

- [unsafe.Alignof](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/#Alignof) returns the required alignment
- [unsafe.Offsetof](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/#Offsetof) computes the offset of a field relative to the start of it's enclosing struct including holes

[1] p354 Donovan, Kernighan, AD, BK, 2016. The GO Programming Language. 1st ed. New York: Addison-Wesley.

Comment: `bool` use memory space, which is different from `[0]byte`. If you replace `[0]byte` with `bool` in bar2 and bar3, both structs will have same size. There is a full example here: https://play.golang.org/p/hNcG9gRlQx

Comment: Yes but the required alignment of [0]byte is 1. You can check the required alignment with `unsafe.Alignof` and compute the offset of a field using `unsafe.Offsetof`. See https://play.golang.org/p/aEEqDBdBZW

Comment: If you print `alignof` and `offset` of the `bool` and `[0]byte` members, you will find that they are the same to two different types. So, that can't explain the struct size difference. See https://play.golang.org/p/oAnH2XodPa