# Other metadata besides struct field tags

Tags: go, metadata

I'm aware of struct field tags to provide metadata for these fields. Are there any other possibilities to provide metadata for methods of structs or interface "methods"?

Background:
I would like to automate the routing of web apps with go and would like to tag methods of Controller-Structs accordingly to the HTTP-Method without abusing the actual method names.

Comment: See related / possible duplicate [Go struct tags with underscore before function names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50387103/go-struct-tags-with-underscore-before-function-names/50391814#50391814).

Comment: No, there is not. Generally speaking, idiomatic Go avoids runtime-dynamic programming in favor of compile-time static programming; what you're describing is something you'd be more likely to see and use in e.g. C#/Java.

Comment: There are various better ways to do what you're describing without resorting to a bunch of slow, complicated reflection code; for example, you could write a route interface with `Get`, `Post` etc methods; you could use `go generate` to dynamically generate static routing; you could give your handlers a hook to register themselves (or have them do it globally in `init` functions); etc.

Comment: Add a struct argument with field tags providing the metadata:  `func (x *X) handler(_ struct {_ \`method:"get"\`}, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {}`.   See earlier comment for preferred approaches.