# Struct type first line: _ struct{}

Tags: go

I see this line of code at the begin of any struct type all over the `github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/ec2`:

```
type InstanceState struct {
    _ struct{} `type:"structure"` <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
...
}
```

Can someone tell me how this is being used and what does it do exactly?

update: looking at https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/blob/master/service/ec2/api.go line 78405(cannot link to git as file is too big for github to show)

Comment: You should add a link to the struct definition.

Comment: github doesent like me > (Sorry about that, but we can’t show files that are this big right now.) its line 78405 of https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/blob/master/service/ec2/api.go

Comment: It's for code generation and/or reflection. This is a duplicate, i'll try to find the previous question.

Comment: this code is generated so that makes a lot of sense, please do, ty @mkopriva

Comment: @DusanGligoric found it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50387103/go-struct-tags-with-underscore-before-function-names