# Go Struct / Tag Syntax

Tags: go, struct, tagging

I'm looking for an explanation of the below syntax:

```
type GetBucketTaggingInput struct {
    _ struct{} `locationName:"GetBucketTaggingRequest" type:"structure"`

    // The name of the bucket for which to get the tagging information.
    //
    // Bucket is a required field
    Bucket *string `location:"uri" locationName:"Bucket" type:"string" required:"true"`
}
```

Specifically, this line:

```
_ struct{} `locationName:"GetBucketTaggingRequest" type:"structure"`
```

I understand the tags are metadata but how is the metadata used in this context?
Also, I don't understand:

```
_ struct{}
```

Regarding the Bucket variable, again, I'm unsure of the need for the metadata apart maybe from the required field.

Incidentally, this is from the AWS Go SDK.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Go struct tags with underscore before function names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50387103/go-struct-tags-with-underscore-before-function-names)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AWS SDK uses `_ struct{}` to specify metadata for the struct.

`_` is the [blank identifier](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blank_identifier).

`struct{}` is an anonymous struct type with no fields. A value of this has zero size.

`locationName:"GetBucketTaggingRequest" type:"structure"` is a [field tag](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types).

The SDK uses the [reflect](https://godoc.org/reflect) package to find the tag for the field `_`.