# What is the purpose of having an empty struct in a go struct as a field?

Tags: go

For example:

```
rawVote struct {
    _struct  struct{}       `codec:",omitempty,omitemptyarray"`
    Sender   basics.Address `codec:"snd"`
    Round    basics.Round   `codec:"rnd"`
    Period   period         `codec:"per"`
    Step     step           `codec:"step"`
    Proposal proposalValue  `codec:"prop"`
}
```

[this example from Algorand"s source code](https://github.com/algorand/go-algorand/blob/52b68983b8f565dd7d4281ce4050ab7fc15d65e3/agreement/vote.go#L31)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50387103/go-struct-tags-with-underscore-before-function-names

Comment: @ttrasn I have read the question and answers you have provided but I could not figure out the reason why there is an empty struct in this specific example. I agree with  VisioN I want to learn why there is _struct struct{} what is the use case of it. I have look the source code of the project but I could not find and example use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [`codec`](https://godoc.org/github.com/ugorji/go/codec) library implementation (probably a fork of it is being used here), a private field with name `_struct` is used to define tag "settings" for every field of the structure:

```golang
type MyStruct struct {
    _struct bool    `codec:",omitempty"`   //set omitempty for every field
    Field1 string   `codec:"-"`            //skip this field
    Field2 int      `codec:"myName"`       //Use key "myName" in encode stream
    Field3 int32    `codec:",omitempty"`   //use key "Field3". Omit if empty.
    Field4 bool     `codec:"f4,omitempty"` //use key "f4". Omit if empty.
    io.Reader                              //use key "Reader".
    MyStruct        `codec:"my1"`          //use key "my1".
    MyStruct                               //inline it
    ...
}
```

The reason why `struct{}` type is used instead of `bool` because it de-facto means "no data" and looks more appropriate here.

**SOURCE:** https://github.com/algorand/go-codec/blob/master/codec/encode.go#L1418