# How does 'type DoNotCompare [0]func()' prevent comparability in Golang

Tags: go, struct, comparison-operators

Per protobuf [pragma](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/internal/pragma#DoNotCompare)

> ```
> `type DoNotCompare [0]func()`
> DoNotCompare can be embedded in a struct to prevent comparability
> ```

I am confused why `DoNotCompare` could prevent comparability, and try to understand with the following codes. Unfortunately, I am failed. The `NonCompare` struct seems could be comparability.

```golang
type DoNotCompare [0]func()

type NonCompare struct {
    DoNotCompare

    ii int8
}

type Comparer interface {
    Compare(b NonCompare) int
}

func (a NonCompare) Compare(b NonCompare) int {
    if a.ii > b.ii {
        return 1
    }
    return 0
}

func main() {
    var nc1 = NonCompare{ii: 3}
    var nc2 = NonCompare{ii: 5}

    nc1.Compare(nc2)
```

Is there anything am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prevention works on the builtin `==` operator, not on what your `Compare()` method does. Of course it can do whatever you want it to.

But if you try to use `==`:

```
fmt.Println(nc1 == nc2)
```

You get a compile-time error:

```
./prog.go:30:18: invalid operation: nc1 == nc2 (struct containing DoNotCompare cannot be compared)
```

The reason is because values of `func()` type (or any function type) are not comparable, so `[0]func()` values are also not comparable. And structs having a field of a non-comparable type are also not comparable. Rules are listed at [Spec: Comparison operators](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Comparison_operators):

> The equality operators == and != apply to operands that are *comparable*. The ordering operators <, <=, >, and >= apply to operands that are ordered. These terms and the result of the comparisons are defined as follows:
>
> - [...]
> - Struct values are comparable if all their fields are comparable. Two struct values are equal if their corresponding non-[blank](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Blank_identifier) fields are equal.
> - Array values are comparable if values of the array element type are comparable. Two array values are equal if their corresponding elements are equal.
>
> [...] Slice, map, and function values are not comparable.

An array of size `0` is used so the field's size will be 0, not adding anything extra to the struct it is used in. Please note this is only guaranteed if you place 0-size fields to the first place. For details see [Struct has different size if the field order is different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34219232/struct-has-different-size-if-the-field-order-is-different/34219916#34219916).