# [0]func() as "do not compare" sentinel - type

Tags: go

What type is ['do not compare' sentinel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71031299/16648033) in struct definition?

```
type SomeStruct struct {
    _ [0]func() // do not compare
    ...
}
```

What exactly is `[0]func()`? Zero-length slice of `func()` objects? Something else?

Comment: It's an array, not a slice, because it has a given length. The purpose of adding this unnamed, zero-length field to a struct/type is to explicitly make it non-comparable. Any code you write that does something using the comparison operators on instances of `SomeStruct` will result in a compile-time error.

Comment: ```_ func()``` would probably do exactly the same. Does this consume more memory?

Comment: Yes, it's for memory optimisation reasons. Again, this is a compile-time trick/check. A `[0]T` as the first field is a field that is known to be 0 bytes in size, so 0 bytes of memory will be allocated. The field will essentially not exist. Other types have known sizes, and will change the size and layout of the structure. The only other 0-byte type AFAIK is an empty struct type (`struct{}{}`), but that is by definition comparable, so it doesn't do what we want it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, considering my comment might as well be considered an answer:

```
_ [0]func()
```

is to be read as an unnamed field of type `[0]func()`. It's not a slice but rather an array. A slice would be `_ []func`. In this case, the array type is of length 0, so effectively an empty type. You can't store anything in there. This field only serves one purpose:

Because any fields, variables or other names of a function type are by definition incomparable, and as per spec, any struct/type containing a field that cannot be compared becomes overall incomparable. Adding `_ [0]func()` to any type therefore makes code that does this spit out a compile-time error:

```
type Base struct {
    Foo uint64
}

type SomeStruct struct {
    _ [0]func()
    Base // embedded
}

func main() {
    a, b := Base{Foo: 123}, Base{Foo: 123}
    fmt.Println(a == b) // works
    safeA, safeB := SomeStruct{Base: a}, SomeStruct{Base: b}
    fmt.Println(safeA == safeB) // compiler error
}
```

### [Demo here](https://go.dev/play/p/4XRhCjRNTe1)

The reason for using `[0]func()` rather than `func()` or `[]func` is that, when the first fields in a struct are of size zero (which we can only know at compile time for an array, not a slice), then they take up 0 bytes in memory. A `func()` type would not be considered zero bytes in size, so to answer your last question:

Yes, `_ [0]func()` is used instead of `_ func()` for optimisation reasons.